# Redirect in Internet Explorer 11 to a PDF leads to multiple requests

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, redirect, http-status-code-301

I 301-redirect a link to track a click.

```
http://myurl.tld/redirect.php?target=http%3A%2F%2Ftarget.tld%2Ffile.pdf
```

I track the amount of calls and some other stats on `redirect.php`. It works well unless I redirect to a pdf file in Internet Explorer (I tested v11, might affect other versions).
In this case, `redirect.php` tracks dozens of clicks within a few seconds made by the same user.
Using fiddler I found out that the pdf is returned in chunks (HTTP status code `206 Partial Content`) which means several requests are made instead of a single one.
Normally, you would expect the browser to make the subsequent calls to `http://target.tld/file.pdf` when `target.tld` delivers the pdf in chunks and this is exactly what most browsers do.
However, Internet Explorer decides to request `http://myurl.tld/redirect.php?target=http%3A%2F%2Ftarget.tld%2Ffile.pdf` again and again and again instead of requesting the target site.

Now my questions:
**How can I tell IE not to call `myurl.tld` but instead `target.tld`?**
**Can I manipulate the headers in the 301-redirect, so that IE knows to request the file from `target.tld`?**

Comment: Does setting the `Content-Location` header value help at all?

Comment: Are you using `Cache-Control: no-cache`? I think IE honors that and may actively avoid caching the redirect. Even in situations where it makes sense, like ranged transfers of content.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this might have been a bug fix/workaround to a (perceived) bug in IE 9 - which apparently was too agressive in remembering 301 redirects. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/possible-bug-in-ie-with-http-code-301-permanent/33cd03f0-8c82-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5

Try using HTTP 308 instead of 301 for IE 11 and see if that helps your problem.